# jQuery - on jPanelMenu how to close toggled submenu when clicking anywhere outside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on updating the code for an ecommerce site, the mobile menu uses the jQuery plugin jPanelMenu and the code is as follows:

```
var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
    menu: '#mainMenu',
    trigger: '.mobileMenuLink',
    duration: 300
});
jPM.on();

$('.styloSearch').clone().prependTo($('#jPanelMenu-menu'));

$('#jPanelMenu-menu').removeClass("sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows");

$('#jPanelMenu-menu li.menu-parent-item a').click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle();
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

The submenu comes up when you click on a menu item, and it can be closed only by clicking on the menu item again, but I want to be able to click anywhere outside to close the submenu.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use the `$('*')` selector which selects all elements

you need to keep the original function too, and add this:

```
$('*').click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I just tried this but it only lets me open and close the submenu once and then I cannot open any of them. But, also, the main problem persists, and I can only close it by clicking on the menu itself.

Comment: how about this?

 `$('*').click(function(e){
    $('#jPanelMenu-menu').siblings("ul").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});`